# I have a Three columns in the SQL table, I want to show the sum of the total of two columns in the third column. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I show that using MySQL query.

Need Create Script

Table Structure:

Col1 int
Col2 int
Col3 as col1+col2

my query

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
    Col1 integer,
    col2 integer,
    col3   as (Col1+col2)
);
```

error: Error: near line 1: near "as": syntax error

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html , try something if you have problems post code

Comment: Generated columns were introduced in version 5.7 what version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to specify a datatype for col3 otherwise code is fine in 5.7 and above

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
    Col1 integer,
    col2 integer,
    col3  integer as (Col1+col2) virtual
);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wZ62ubbuC3atgKdS3BCXni/0